# How to store strings in CSV with new line characters?

Tags: python, dataset, csv

My question is: what are ways I can store strings in a CSV that contain newline characters (i.e. `\n`), where each data point is in one line?

### Sample data

This is a sample of the data I have:

```
data = [
    ['some text in one line', 1],
    ['text with\nnew line character', 0],
    ['another new\nline character', 1]
]
```

### Target CSV

I want a CSV file, where the first line is `"text,category"` and every subsequent line is an entry from `data`.

### What I tried

Using the `csv` package from Python.

```
import csv
field_names = ['text', 'category']

# Writing
with open('file.csv', 'w+', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    csvwriter = csv.DictWriter(file, field_names)
    csvwriter.writeheader()
    for d in data:
        csvwriter.writerow({'text': d[0], 'category':d[1]})

# Reading
with open('file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    csvreader = csv.DictReader(file, field_names)
    data = []
    for line in csvreader:
        data.append([line['text'], line['category']])
```

I can read and write, but the output `file.csv` is the following:

> text,category
>
> some text in one line,1
>
> "text with
>
> new line character",0
>
> "another new
>
> line character",1

So not one line per data point.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a simple solution: Replace all `\n` with `\\n` before saving to CSV. This will preserve the newline characters.

```
df.loc[:, "Column_Name"] = df["Column_Name"].apply(lambda x: x.replace('\n', '\\n'))
df.to_csv("df.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Quick and precise, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the best answer imo. Short and to the point.

Comment: Years later this issue still haunts me. I like this solution more now as well.

Answer (score 10):

I assume that you want to keep the newlines in the strings for some reason after you have loaded the csv files from disk. Also that this is done again in Python. My solution will require Python 3, although the principle could be applied to Python 2.

### The main trick

This is to replace the `\n` characters before writing with a weird character that otherwise wouldn't be included, then to swap that weird character back for `\n` after reading the file back from disk.

For my weird character, I will use the *Icelandic thorn*: Þ, but you can choose anything that should otherwise not appear in your text variables.
Its name, as defined in the standardised Unicode specification is: **LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN**. You can use it in Python 3 a couple of ways:

```py
    weird_literal = 'þ'
    weird_name = '\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER THORN}'
    weird_char = '\xfe'  # hex representation
    weird_literal == weird_name == weird_char  # True
```

That `\N` is pretty cool (and works in python 3.6 inside formatted strings too)... it basically allows you to pass the **N**ame of a character, as per Unicode's specification.

An alternative character that may serve as a good standard is `'\u2063'` (INVISIBLE SEPARATOR).

### Replacing `\n`

Now we use this weird character to replace `'\n'`. Here are the two ways that pop into my mind for achieving this:

1. using a list comprehension on your list of lists: `data`:

   ```
    new_data = [[sample[0].replace('\n', weird_char) + weird_char, sample[1]]
                 for sample in data]
   ```
2. putting the data into a dataframe, and using replace on the whole `text` column in one go

   ```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['text', 'category'])
    df1.text = df.text.str.replace('\n', weird_char)
   ```

The resulting dataframe looks like this, with newlines replaced:

```
               text              category
0         some text in one line      1   
1  text withþnew line character      0   
2    another newþline character      1
```

### Writing the results to disk

Now we write either of those identical dataframes to disk. I set `index=False` as you said you don't want row numbers to be in the CSV:

```
FILE = '~/path/to/test_file.csv'
df.to_csv(FILE, index=False)
```

What does it look like on disk?

> text,category

> some text in one line,1

> text withþnew line character,0

> another newþline character,1

### Getting the original data back from disk

Read the data back from file:

```
new_df = pd.read_csv(FILE)
```

And we can replace the `Þ` characters back to `\n`:

```
new_df.text = new_df.text.str.replace(weird_char, '\n')
```

And the final DataFrame:

```
new_df
               text               category
0          some text in one line      1   
1  text with\nnew line character      0   
2    another new\nline character      1
```

If you want things back into your list of lists, then you can do this:

```
original_lists = [[text, category] for index, text, category in old_df_again.itertuples()]
```

Which looks like this:

```
[['some text in one line', 1],
 ['text with\nnew line character', 0],
 ['another new\nline character', 1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I only see issues in the case I want to share this file with other people. How will they know that this characters is to represent a new line? Is there such a things a 'meta-data' for CSV files? Or is better to publish it along with a `README`? (p.s. thanks for the `\N{}` trick)

Comment: @BrunoGL - You could replace it with all caps `NEWLINECHAR` or something else. If people want to read these csv files though in a normal editor, maybe the best thing would be to export to a spreadsheet format instead. Otherwise, if you are just storing the data to be loaded again later, consider a binary format such as `pickle`. If you want to store meta-data along with the actual data, all in a single file, you could look at the HDFS files... these are, however, not files you can open with a normal text editor i.e. you need to use a programming language.